# Can the TensorFlow's map_and_batch be used with padded batches?

Tags: python, tensorflow, multiprocessing

From TensorFlow's article on [Data Input Pipeline Performance](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/performance/datasets) I can see that in some cases it makes sense to use the `map_and_batch` function. However, I use padded shapes (`tf.data.padded_batch()`) and would like to know if there's still a way to use the suggested `map_and_batch`. The documentation doesn't explain this case.

Thank you

Comment: Are you looking for an equivalent fused operation of map and padded_batch?